# ajax dropdown extender at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-ajax

I've got a textbox with an ajax dropdown extender. How do I make it look like image 2 at runtime and not only when hovering over the textbox. 
The textbox with the "downbutton" should look like image 2 at design time

[image: Image 2 to look like at runtime]

How do I do this or some good reading material on how to do this?

EDIT

All I've done is this so far as I'm trying to first display it correctly, otherwise i will have to find another way:

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>

       <asp:TextBox ID="txtResidence" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:DropDownExtender ID="txtResidence_DropDownExtender" runat="server" 
           DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtResidence"
           DropDownControlID="pnlRes">
       </asp:DropDownExtender>

   </div>
   <div>
         <asp:Panel ID="pnlRes" runat="server">
        <asp:TreeView ID="ResidenceTreeView" runat="server" ShowLines="true" PopulateNodesFromClient="false" BackColor="#99CCFF" style="width:100%" ShowExpandCollapse="false">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="1" Value="1">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="1.1" Value="1.1"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="1.2" Value="1.2"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="2" Value="2">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="2.1" Value="2.1"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="2.2" Value="2.2"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
        </asp:TreeView>
        </asp:Panel>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you post some code. which can be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  

function pageLoad()
{
      $find('txtResidence_txtResidence_DropDownExtender')._dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover();
  $find('txtResidence_txtResidence_DropDownExtender').unhover = VisibleMe;
}

function VisibleMe()
{
    $find('txtResidence_txtResidence_DropDownExtender')._dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover();
}
```

Comment: It is giving me an error of:  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '_dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover': object is null or undefined" ? Haven't really done a lot of js....

Comment: I think the problem is with MasterPage

Comment: Try using `$find('<%= 'txtResidence_txtResidence_DropDownExtender.ClientID %>')`